# Flutter_Map: How do I set a boolean true or false based on zoom distance?

Tags: flutter

For instance if map zoom is greater than 10 then boolean = true and if map zoom is less than 10 then boolean = false.

Would it be possible for anyone to provide an example in code so I can study it.

Thanks for you help!

I tried using StreamController but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the google_maps_flutter, you have a function ***onCameraMove*** parameter.

Here is an example :

```
void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    setState(() {
      // Check if the current zoom is greater than or equal to 10
      isZoomGreaterThanOrEqualTo10 = position.zoom >= 10;
    });
}

GoogleMap(
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      _controller = controller;
    },
    onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
      zoom: 10.0,
    ),
  ),
```